# How to know the updated attributes in an xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, database, crud

Q:

I allow my user to upload an `xml` file to insert its contents in my database.

I ask if there's some idea to know the attributes which have been changed to update the equivalent fields in my database without uploading the updated file again(clear all the data related to this file and insert it again).

Is there some way rather than a form .

## My xml snip:

```
<day name="Saturday" short="Sa" day="0"/>
<day name="Sunday" short="Su" day="1"/>
<day name="Monday" short="Mo" day="2"/>
<day name="Tuesday" short="Tu" day="3"/>
<day name="Wednesday" short="We" day="4"/>
<day name="Thursday" short="Th" day="5"/>
```

---

## My .cs snip :

```
                        List<Day> days = new List<Day>();//List of days.
                        IEnumerable<DayNode> resultDays = ReadDayNodes(targetFileName);
                        foreach (DayNode name in resultDays)
                        {
                            Day day = new Day();

                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl_batch.SelectedValue))
                                day.BatchNum = int.Parse(ddl_batch.SelectedValue);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl_department.SelectedValue))
                                day.DepCode = int.Parse(ddl_department.SelectedValue);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddl_study.SelectedValue))
                                day.StudyCode = int.Parse(ddl_study.SelectedValue);
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name.Day))
                                day.DayId = name.Day;
                            day.ShortName = name.Short;
                            day.Name = name.Name;
                            days.Add(day);
                        }
    /********************************************************************************************************************/
            private struct DayNode
            {
                public string Name { get; private set; }
                public string Short { get; private set; }
                public string Day { get; private set; }
                public DayNode(string Name, string Short, string Day)
                    : this()
                {
                    this.Name = Name;
                    this.Short = Short;
                    this.Day = Day;
                }
            }
        /********************************************************************************************************************/
        private static IEnumerable<DayNode> ReadDayNodes(string filePath)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            using (XmlReader xrdr = new XmlTextReader(fs))
                while (xrdr.Read())
                    if (xrdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xrdr.LocalName == "day")
                        yield return new DayNode(xrdr.GetAttribute("name"), xrdr.GetAttribute("short"), xrdr.GetAttribute("day"));
        }
        /********************************************************************************************************************/
          resultDay = CommonUitilities.InsertDays(days);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  may pass `InputStream` (FileUpload#PostedFile) object of uploaded file to the `XDocument.Load()` method (Linq-XML) to read/parse XML document. After that you may compare xml data against the database.

Comment: You can easily compare values when Linq-SQL or EDM is used at your site instead of Core ADO.NET.

Comment: I use `informix database`.

I edit my question and put some code . Could u give me simple example please.

Comment: @just_name - So you want to compare an object (content) of DayNode with upload XML content. Post sample xml data.

Comment: @just_name - I think you should have delete previous records and insert data from uploaded file instead of comparing and updating each one value.

Comment: hmmmmm .no way except this one ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5978/discussion-between-just-name-and-avd)